# Is there a way to create Origen commands for the entire linux install?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am familiar with how to create application commands from [this doc](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/commands/).  I wonder if there is a way to configure site-wide commands that would fetch a particular application and change the CWD to the cloned application.  Or would this be more in the rake solution space?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything really belongs in the rake solution space.

Origen does support the concept of creating a plugin which adds global commands - http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/plugins/creating/#Sharing_Global_Commands

The procedure is to create a regular Origen plugin, and then configure it with a global command launcher as in this example - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_sim/blob/master/config/application.rb#L32

Then `gem install my_plugin` to your global Ruby environment. Then, anywhere in your environment, including outside of application workspaces, you will be able to run `origen my_plugin_command`.